# Posting Link to Twitter in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to post URL to twitter from my WP7 app is there any way I could do it in C# with out using the web authentication ?

The use case is some thing like.

1) I upload a picture to flickr website and get the URL.

2) I want to post the URL in Twitter . It should just ask me the username and password then postit on my twitter

any comments or suggestions would be great

Comment: Why would you not want to use the web authentication? It's there for a reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Mango you can use the [ShareLinkTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.sharelinktask%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) which lets a user share with any linked social networking site on the phone. Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn and Windows Live.

If you are looking on 7.0 apps then you will need to go down the oAuth etc path. Look at `TweetSharp`

Edit: Code sample for `ShareLinkTask`

```
var task = new ShareLinkTask() {
  LinkUri = new Uri("http://www.example.com", UriKind.Absolute),
  Message = "a message",
  Title = "a title"
};
task.Show();
```

Comment: It sounds like ShareLinkTask is the best way to go if you're targetting Mango as the user has already potentially added their Twitter account to the phone.

Comment: can you provide me with some sample code on how to use the API

Comment: I added a code sample for ShareLinkTask, there is too much involved to add one for TweetSharp.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. Just one more question will the above code work in emulator ?

Comment: I don't believe it does as you can not set up those accounts. But I have tested it on device and API works fine.

Comment: Is it possible to detect whether the user has registered a fb/twitter account in the device? So we can decide to either user ShareLinkTask or manual authentication.. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know of any way to do this. I think you would need to give them the option in the app.

Comment: However you should be aware that if the user doesn't have the social account setup on the phone, the call will just return.

Comment: @ Mugunthan Ravichandran It wont work in emulator , its required to test in real(mango) device only.